# PHP - Google API / Gmail API - How to set quotaUser?

Tags: php, google-api, gmail-api

I need to enforce per-user quotas on my Google API and Gmail API calls.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/query-parameters

How do I set **quotaUser** using PHP?

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('My App');
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setRedirectUri('my url');
$client->setScopes(
    array( Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_SEND,
           'email',
           'profile',
           'openid'
    )
);

$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

$service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
$info = $service->userinfo->get();

$gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$gmail->users_messages->send('me', 'my message');
```

Answer (score 0):

To enforce per-user quotas, you need to assign a unique value (an email for example) to the “quotaUser” field or assign the users' IP to the “userIP” field. [1]

Here it's the working code example to enforce per-user quotas (it worked for me in my test application using the Gmail quickstart [2] and adding the code below):

```
$optParams = array('quotaUser' => "username@gsuite-domain.com");
$response = $gmail->users_messages->send("me", $message, $optParams);
```

In the Google Cloud platform console (console.cloud.google.com) you can edit the quota limit per user and per API. Read the instructions on how to edit quota limits [3].

You can check the “quota units” used per each Gmail API method, this way you could calculate how much quota day limit you wish. [4].

PHP UserMessages_Resource class documentation from Gmail API [5].

[1] https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/query-parameters

[2] https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php

[3] https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage

[4] https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota

[5] https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Gmail_UsersMessages_Resource.html